# Tripods/Grips for Handheld Recorders

Tags: field-recording, equipment, gear, tripod

Does anyone have some suggestions for a small and portable tripod or grip for a basic handheld field recorder with tripod mount?

I'm mainly looking for something that will help reduce handling noise...

Answer (score 3):

What about the [Gorillapod](http://joby.com/gorillapod)? I haven't used it myself, but I think it is a great little tripod which is extremely flexible so you can even fold it around the branches of a tree. This would be my choice.

Comment: Hey Hugo, I picked up a Gorillapod this morning and it's pretty slick - very small and will work as a grip when you fold the legs in. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You're welcome Joel. I hope it makes your recordings sound great!

Answer (score 1):

For a tripod, I'd recommend one of [those](http://www.amazon.com/Smith-Victor-PG820MT-Tripod-Multi-position/dp/B000IN9CV2). Cheap, with flexible legs and a ball head.
Use it all the time for my little photo camera, and it also holds a Zoom recorder easily. I don't know if handling noise will be really lower, but the collapsed mini tripod also works great as a simple grip.

If that's not for you, there are lots of mini tripods ranging from $ 0,99 to $ 40,-.
[Small overview](http://www.google.com/products?hl=en&q=flexible+mini+tripod&rlz=1B3GGGL_enNL240NL240&um=1&ie=UTF-8&ei=vSa6S7vnLpSnOK6MkaEL&sa=X&oi=product_result_group&ct=title&resnum=1&ved=0CBQQrQQwAA)

Answer (score 1):

I use a Manfrotto 001B nano stand, it collapses down to 48 cm and can extend up to 1.9 m.  It can carry 1.5 kg and weighs only 0.93 kg.  It is also reliable and does not look out of place on a set.

http://www.manfrotto.com/Jahia/site/manfrotto/cache/off/pid/2489?livid=24&idx=28

Comment: +1 on the 001B nano's. Have two, outfitted with extendible boom arms, work better than my studio mic stands, ultra-portable! (Just get the right 3/8" adapters for pistol grips and boompoles!)

Answer (score 0):

For a mini tripod, I'd also go for the [Gorillapod](http://joby.com/gorillapod).

If you're looking for something that will give you height too then you would need a proper tripod with expendable legs. I just bought myself a really nice and small one, it's super light and I can hook up one mic on top and one at the bottom. The legs also bend into pretty wide angles so if you don't have much space you can lift one leg up against a ledge or have the tripod very low. The tripod is the [Hahnel Triad 30 Lite](http://www.hahnel.ie/index.cfm?page=tripods&id=57&pId=57).

[image]
<sub>(source: [hahnel.ie](http://www.hahnel.ie/contentFiles/genericProducts/Tripod_A4_Triad_30Lite(1).jpg?uid=1252502980402))</sub>

Comment: Hey Andrew, if you get a moment, would love to know about that tripod - sounds like a nice piece for certain situations.

Comment: @Joel-Raabe here, I've updated my answer with the name of the tripod. 

Answer (score 0):

relatedly, Rycote make Windjammers for specific models of portable recorders - a good investment if you are recording outdoors a lot

http://www.rycote.com/products/families/mini-windjammers-handheld-recorder

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, everyone - very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I went with an inexpensive little AKG stand:

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/286148-REG/AKG_KM231_1_231_1_Miniature_Tripod_Microphone.html

I also find that with this plus a shock mount, I can fold the legs up and hold it like a pistol grip without any handling noise.

Answer (score 0):

I recently went for a Benro TRA068 which looks similar to that Hahnel posted above. So far I'm satisfied with it. I like it because it can be used for photography or as a mic stand and its very light and portable.
http://www.benro.com/products_details_TRA068.html